# Improving a parsing solution

Tags: c#, regex, string, web-services, text

So the basic premise of the problem is that we have a text file that has a list of data that may or may or not be a web service. From that list of web services that exists in the text file, I want to parse the web methods available for each web service and publish this data to an excel sheet.

I'll give you an example of what the test data looks like:

```
<Resource Name="APP1">
    <Uri UriType="PAGE" ResourceUri="http://exampleurl/default.aspx" />
</Resource>
<Resource Name="App2">
    <Uri UriType="PAGE" ResourceUri="http://exampleurl2/example.aspx" />
</Resource>
<Resource Name="App3">
    <Uri UriType="PAGE" ResourceUri="http://exampleurl3/exampleapp.asmx" />
</Resource>
```

Basically, the last line is the line I would like to use. The other example of a useable line is

```
<Resource Name="Example" WSDL="http://example.wsdl">
    <Uri UriType="ASMX" ResourceUri="http://example.asmx" />
</Resource>
```

So, I am essentially looking for `.asmx` and `.wsdl` files. The way I thought about the problem was to standardize my input to only look for WSDLs for each of these web services, so for URLs that have `.asmx` I will be adding `?wsdl`.

Now, below a solution I have implemented. Since there are thousands of web services located in the source file, and potentially n web methods, I am seeing execution time take up to 1-2 hours. I am wondering if this solution can be improved further in order to speed up the runtime.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.Data;
using ClosedXML.Excel;

namespace ParseWebservices
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var lines = File.ReadAllText(@"PATH\SourceFIle.xml");
            int count = 0;
            string text = "";
            DataTable Webservices= new DataTable();
            Webservices.Columns.Add("Wsdl URL");
            Webservices.Columns.Add("Webservice Name");
            Webservices.Columns.Add("WebMethod");

            Regex r = new Regex("(?<=ResourceUri=\")(.*)(.asmx)(?=\")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Match m = r.Match(lines.ToString());
            while (m.Success)
            {


                try
                {

                    string[] test = m.ToString().Split('/');
                    string webservicename = test[test.Length - 1].Replace(".asmx", "");
                    string wsdlurl="";

                    var webClient = new WebClient();
                    string readHtml="";
                    try
                    {
                        readHtml = webClient.DownloadString(wsdlurl);
                    }
                    catch (Exception excxx)
                    {
                        wsdlurl = m.ToString().Replace(".asmx", ".wsdl");
                        readHtml = webClient.DownloadString(wsdlurl);
                    }

                    int count2 = 0;
                    string text2 = "";
                    Regex r2 = new Regex(@"(?<=s:element name\=\"")(.*)(?=Response"")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    Match m2 = r2.Match(readHtml);
                    while (m2.Success)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = Webservices.NewRow();

                        dr[0] = wsdlurl;
                        dr[1] = webservicename;
                        dr[2] = m2.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine(wsdlurl + "\n" + webservicename + "\n" + m2.ToString());
                        Webservices.Rows.Add(dr);
                        count2++;
                        m2 = m2.NextMatch();
                    }
                    count++;
                    m = m.NextMatch();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    m = m.NextMatch();
                }
            }

            XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
            wb.Worksheets.Add(Webservices, "Example");
            wb.SaveAs(@"PATH\example.xlsx");
        }
    }
}
```

One thing I don't like about this solution is that it relies on exceptions. Because the regex matches `.asmx` strings, I realized it would fail to find strings that `.wsdl`. But I also noticed that in  the source text that contains a `.wsdl`, the `.asmx` prefix is exactly the same. So I added that error handling for those test cases, but definitely not ideal.

Anyway, I would appreciate any suggestions on how to improve and make it faster (and better!).

Comment: That document seems to be perfectly valid XML, have you tried to use XDocument or XmlDocument to parse the data? it will be a lot faster than using a regex to parse a very big file.

Comment: You might be taking a wrong approach here.  If your input files are in XML, you should look into XML parsing and not regex.

Comment: Also, instead of checking serially all the url's create in another thread a queue wich consumes these url's and does these tests on pararlell

Comment: I tried loading it into XMLdocument, but the behavior I was seeing was that the nodes were not providing the names correctly (I was seeing null for the value attached to the tags). However, it is possible that  I was not looking in the right place since it was my first time using the lib.

Comment: Also, could you please provide insight into why the XML lib is faster than the regex? I just want to understand the reasoning. The parallel stuff definitely makes sense though, I didn't think of that ( and have never tried it, but it seems like a good opportunity).

Answer (score 1):

That's slow because it's all done on one thread!  (Whether it's xml or regex will have very little to do with the slowness: it's all the inline web requests that are really slowing you down)

Without your source file it's hard to do a working example, so I've written a helper extension to load a list of Urls asynchronously - you'll obviously need to fill your code around it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParseWebservices
{
    static class UrlLoaderExtension
    {
    public static async Task<ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>> LoadUrls(this IEnumerable<string> urls)
    {
        var result = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,string>();                
        Task[] tasks = urls.Select(url => {
            return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    // Console.WriteLine("Thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    try
                    {
                        var r = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
                        result[url] = r;
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        result[url] = err.Message;
                    }
                }
            });
        }).ToArray();                
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        return result;
    }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var requests = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,string>();

            // load desired urls into the structure
            requests["http://www.microsoft.com"] = null;
            requests["http://www.google.com"] = null;
            requests["http://www.google.com/asdfdsaf"] = null;

            try
            {
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    requests = await requests.Keys.LoadUrls();
                }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished loading data concurrently");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // this part is synchronous (it's not waiting for IO)
            foreach(var url in requests.Keys)
            {
                var response = requests[url];
                Console.WriteLine(response); // 
                Console.WriteLine("Response from " + url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }



            Console.Write("DONE");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you put your urls into this demo to get an idea of how much quicker you'll be able to load the data:  the point where it tells you it's finished loading is when it has all the responses collected.

Then, after you've determined how (very!) much faster this is, then you'll be motivated to fill your other logic in around it :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: @user2044754 Did you get to give this a try? :)

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments suggest, if your example is valid XML, I suspect an XML parsing solution may be easier to work with and faster than Regex. You could try something like:

```
var files = XElement.Parse(xmlString)
    .Descendants("Resource").SelectMany(resource =>
    {
        XAttribute wsdlAttribute = resource.Attribute("WSDL");
        XAttribute resourceUriAttribute = resource.Element("Uri").Attribute("ResourceUri");
        if (wsdlAttribute != null)
            return new[] { wsdlAttribute.Value, resourceUriAttribute.Value };
        else
            return new[] { resourceUriAttribute.Value };
    }).Select(uri => Path.GetFileName(uri));
```

Which returns:

- default.aspx
- example.aspx
- exampleapp.asmx
- example.wsdl
- example.asmx

Using the testing xml string I created from your post:

```
        string xmlString = 
@"<Root>
    <Resource Name=""APP1"">
        <Uri UriType=""PAGE"" ResourceUri=""http://exampleurl/default.aspx"" />
    </Resource>
    <Resource Name=""App2"">
        <Uri UriType=""PAGE"" ResourceUri=""http://exampleurl2/example.aspx"" />
    </Resource>
    <Resource Name=""App3"">
        <Uri UriType=""PAGE"" ResourceUri=""http://exampleurl3/exampleapp.asmx"" />
    </Resource>
    <Resource Name=""Example"" WSDL=""http://example.wsdl"">
        <Uri UriType=""ASMX"" ResourceUri=""http://example.asmx"" />
    </Resource>
</Root>";
```

I can't promise that it will be faster than your solution, but you are more than welcome to test it! You could also thread this if you have multiple files to process.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot, and report back with results!